# Can you translate this for me?

Tags: translation, meaning

Can you tell me what is this means? It's on my T-Shirt.
https://gyazo.com/3736d4a55d523b427086f5c531271556

Answer (score 2):

That means no problem.

問題 is translated to a problem.
ない is 無い. "Aが無い" is translated to "There is not A."